# Transform a org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] into Parallelized collections

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, sequence, rdd

I've a csv file in my HDFS with a collection of products like:

```
[56]
[85,66,73]
[57]
[8,16]
[25,96,22,17]
[83,61]
```

I'm trying to apply the Association Rules algorithm in my code. For that I need to run this:

```
scala> val data = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/data")
data: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = /user/cloudera/data MapPartitionsRDD[294] at textFile at <console>:38

scala> val distData = sc.parallelize(data)
```

But when I submit this I'm getting this error:

```
<console>:40: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]
 required: Seq[?]
Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
         val distData = sc.parallelize(data)
```

How can I transform a RDD[String] in a Sequence collection?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are facing is simple. The error show to you.

To parallelize a object in spark you should add a `Seq()` object. And you are trying to add a `RDD[String]` object.

The RDD is already parallelized, the textFile method parallelize the file elements by lines in your cluster.

You can check the method description here:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html